# gradient color in integer-array android

Tags: android, colors, gradient

i am using random color for my cardview background by integer-array in color.xml file

color.xml :

```
<item name="Gold" type="color">#FFFFD700</item>
<item name="Orange" type="color">#DSADSA</item>
<item name="LightSalmon" type="color">#EWQ5645W</item>

<integer-array name="androidcolors">
    <item>@color/Gold</item>
    <item>@color/Orange</item>
    <item>@color/LightSalmon</item>
</integer-array>
```

but i want gradient color for my backgrounds and i tried this:

```
<integer-array name="androidcolors">
    <item><gradient android:endColor="@color/blue" android:startColor="@color/darkblue" /></item>
</integer-array>
```

it doesn't work and i search any where and i think no body used this :| can you help me guys how to use gradient in integer-array or color.xml file ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,
1. Create a drawable colors,For ex:

```
 card_drawable_bg.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
android:startColor="#ff9a6922"
android:centerColor="#ff9a4025"
android:endColor="#ff9a0e32"
android:angle="45"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

2. TypedArray is what you are looking for. I have samples using it. If you are interested, take a look at codes below:

First, integer-array in res/values/arrays.xml:

```
    <integer-array name="frag_home_ids">
    <item>@drawable/card_drawable_bg</item>

</integer-array>
```

Second, get resource integer values programmatically:

```
    TypedArray tArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(
            R.array.frag_home_ids);
int count = tArray.length();
int[] ids = new int[count];
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    ids[i] = tArray.getResourceId(i, 0);
}
//Recycles the TypedArray, to be re-used by a later caller. 
//After calling this function you must not ever touch the typed array again.
tArray.recycle();
```

Third, call the integer values like this:

holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ids[position]);

You can get integer values of string, color, integer, layout, menu...in this way.Hope it will help you.

Comment: create another drawable and add inside the integer array

Comment: read this link to know more about gradient colors http://www.singhajit.com/gradient-color-in-android/

Comment: <integer-array name="androidcolors">
        <item>@drawable/g1</item>
        <item>@drawable/g2</item>
        <item>@drawable/g3</item>
    </integer-array>

i did it but show white background(null bg)

Comment: i think its about cardView.setCardBackgroundColor
i am using gradient

Comment: Hi you there?Have you got solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml file and place it in the Drawable folder. Use the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#8300bf"
    android:centerColor="#768087"
    android:endColor="#FF9000"
    android:angle="-90"
    android:type="linear"/>
```

Specify the startColor and endColor. In your LinearLayout, set the background by `setBackground="@drawable/Your Gradient Filename"`.

Comment: i want a lot of gradient colors

Comment: Using xml you can use a maximum of 3 colors (Check the edited answer). If you want to use more, you have to use `android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable`.

Comment: Do you want the colors to keep changing after a fixed time period?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L99TH.jpg
look at this picture.i am creating it.i did it but just have problem with background.my page have solid backgrounds and i want to have gradient backgrounds...

Comment: Please attach your LinearLayout.

Comment: To set the background color of a card, use the `cardView:cardBackgroundColor="@drawable/Your Gradient Filename"` attribute.

Comment: int[] androidColors = holder.itemView.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
        int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
        holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(randomAndroidColor);

i set random background by this code with integer-array